# How to set lang or change locale in google chart?

Tags: html, css, charts

Is there a work solution to set lang or change locale in google chart?

```js
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    
    google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  language: 'fr'
});
    

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Population');



      data.addRows([
        [new Date(2009, 08, 01),  6242],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 02),  6319],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 03),  6396],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 04),  6473],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 05),  6551],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 06),  6630],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 07),  6709],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 08),  6788]
      ]);

      var linearOptions = {
        title: 'Simple line chart',
        legend: 'none',
        width: 450,
        height: 200,
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'MASS',
          ticks: [0, 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000]
        }
      };

      var logOptions = {
        title: 'Simple line chart',
        legend: 'none',
        width: 450,
        height: 200,
         hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'MASS',
          scaleType: 'log',
          ticks: [0, 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000]
        }
      };

      var linearChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linear_div'));
       linearChart.draw(data, linearOptions);

      var logChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('log_div'));
      logChart.draw(data, logOptions);
    }
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  
      <table class="columns">
    <tr>
      <th>Linear Scale</th>
      <th>Log Scale</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="linear_div"></div></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'line'], language: 'fr'} );
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    
  
    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Population');



      data.addRows([
        [new Date(2009, 08, 01),  6242],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 02),  6319],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 03),  6396],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 04),  6473],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 05),  6551],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 06),  6630],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 07),  6709],
        [new Date(2009, 08, 08),  6788]
      ]);

      var linearOptions = {
        title: 'Simple line chart',
        legend: 'none',
        width: 450,
        height: 200,
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'MASS',
          ticks: [0, 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000]
        }
      };

      var logOptions = {
        title: 'Simple line chart',
        legend: 'none',
        width: 450,
        height: 200,
         hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'MASS',
          scaleType: 'log',
          ticks: [0, 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000]
        }
      };

      var linearChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linear_div'));
       linearChart.draw(data, linearOptions);

      var logChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('log_div'));
      logChart.draw(data, logOptions);
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  
      <table class="columns">
    <tr>
      <th>Linear Scale</th>
      <th>Log Scale</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="linear_div"></div></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
```